# Change number of values in array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, size

Is it possible to reset the number of values in an array after it's already been set?
I have defined the number of values in the array through a variable, later that variable is updated by the user and I need to size of the array to be updated with it.

Ie:

```
numberOfPeople = 2;
Person person[] = new Person[numberOfPeople];
```

Later:

```
if(valueSelected == 3) {
numberOfPeople = 3; }
```

Above is just a very simplified example but basically that's what I've got, I just need the array size to actually change when the `if` statement being executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't change the length of the array once it's been created.

For that, I'd recommend using an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object o = new Object();
arrayList.add(obj);
```

It can keep growing to any length you'd like.

You can read more about `ArrayList`s from the [official oracle document here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

For removing entries, just use the `.remove()` method:

Either

```
arrayList.remove(Object o); //removes occurrence of that object
```

OR

```
int index = 0;
arrayList.remove(index);  //removes the object at index 0
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll do some further research into ArrayLists. I them to be able to handle removing entries from the list too (the user might just have 1 person instead of the default 2), but from my quick search it seems that's possible so hopefully it should work out.

Comment: @Josh sure. See my edit. It is very easy with an ArrayList

Comment: Great thanks! 95% sure that'll work for me so I'll mark as solved. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to stick with using arrays, though, you'd have to make a new array with a bigger size and copy all the data from the old one into the new one.

I'd still suggest Alex K's answer. It's a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try make Array Lists work for me first. Nice to know about options though.